# WTForms validators.optional: continue validation of empty fields?

Tags: python, validation, wtforms

I have a problem with WTForms validators.optional() because it stops the validation chain  if the field is empty ([WTForms docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html)). This means that the validation does not continue with custom functions, which can result in type errors.

Code example:

```
class MyForm(form):
    myfield = TextField('My Field', [validators.Optional()])

    def validate_myfield(form, field):
        field.data = unicode(field.data)
```

Is there any way or workaround to continue the validation chain even if the optional content is empty, maybe using [custom validators](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html#custom-validators)?

If I am approaching the problem in the wrong way, a hint at the right direction would be helpful!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just place custom validators before optional in the list of validators? (validators are evaluated in order)

Comment: Your comment helped, make it an answer so that I can select it.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to continue validation if the field is empty? Normally you can react to empty values only in two ways, either it is an error (no optional), or it is not an error (is optional) and you handle it in some constant way (since the value is always the same). If you are getting type errors, are you trying to do something in the validators that doesn't really belong there? I'm not familiar with WTForms, but apparently you can make custom fields, that can handle any custom parsing requirements, too.

Comment: For empty values I'm using validators to conditionally change field.data. The condition is data from another field. It works but maybe custom fields handle this better?

Comment: Custom fields do seem like a better place to handle that. I'd guess that most people wouldn't expect a validator to modify any data. So doing it with custom fields could make the code easier for other people to understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just change the order in which your validators are listed. If your custom validators are placed before the optional validator it should provide the desired effect as they're evaluated in order.

Comment: I understand this is 10 years late, but in the more recent versions of WTForms, adding Optional cancels out all of the other validation checks.